# while (p=strtok(NULL,",")) warning :possible incorrect assignment

Tags: c++, c

There is a code and I am getting errors in

```
Line 8: array size too large
line 9: array size too large 
line 28 while (p=strtok(NULL,",")) warning :possible incorrect assignment
```

so can you please suggest me how to handle this warning/errors?

**Code:**

> /* convert csv data to libsvm/svm-light format */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[10000000];
float feature[100000];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE *fp;

    if(argc!=2) { fprintf(stderr,"Usage %s filename\n",argv[0]); }
    if((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't open input file %s\n",argv[1]);
    }

    while(fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]\n",buf)==1)
    {
        int i=0,j;
        char *p=strtok(buf,",");

        feature[i++]=atof(p);

        while((p=strtok(NULL,",")))
            feature[i++]=atof(p);

        //      --i;
        /*
        if ((int) feature[i]==1)
        printf("-1 ");
    else
        printf("+1 ");
       */
       //       printf("%f ", feature[1]);
        printf("%d ", (int) feature[0]);
        for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        printf(" %d:%f",j,feature[j]);


        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Vivek You're wrong. `strtok` returned value has to be assigned, not only tested.

Comment: Okay I deleted thje misleading comment, I was taken away by the warning. Didn't pay attention to the logic of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to store the value returned from `strtok` into variable `p`, and at the same time to check whether this value is NULL or not.

I suggest you write it the following way, which is equivalent, and more descriptive compared to how it is currently written.

```
while( ( p=strtok(NULL,",") )!=NULL )
```

Regarding the *array size too large* errors, you should consider using dynamic allocation using `malloc` and `free` for both arrays in C, or using `std::vector` in C++.

Comment: thknx a lot for your help according to your suggestion i had used malloc and free but still i am getting an error in it . so could you help me out??? .... again thanks a lot